# Result always go in same condition

Tags: php, mysqli

I have one simple script which I want to check if database isn't updated last 3 hours to use `IF` block if is updated to use `ELSE`. What I found is that it is always use `IF` condition and never go in else block.

```
public static function getPrice() {

     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "myUsername";
     $password = "myPassword";
     $dbname = "myDbName"; 

     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }             
     $query = "select update_time from price";

     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {  
         if (time() - strtotime($row['update_time']) > 3 * 3600)
         {      
            $urldata = get_curl_content('https://example.com/api');
            $rates = json_decode($urldata, TRUE);
    
            $price = @$rates['USD'];
            echo 'a';
         }    
         else {         
            $price = $row['price']; 
            echo 'b';       
         }
     }
     return $price;
}
```

No matter how what is in `$row['update_time']` it is always showing what is it in `IF`... i.e. from the url not from database.

What I miss here?

UPDATE: in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT update_time FROM  `price`
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total)
```

`0-0` but I see the result.. it's a table without primary key etc. Just two columns `price` and `update_time`

[image]

UPDATE2:

`echo (time() - strtotime($row['update_time']))` -> 54143

`echo strtotime($row['update_time'])` -> 1477552149

Comment: echo `(time() - strtotime($row['update_time'])` you will get your answer

Comment: Thank's. When I echo update_time it turn outs that `$row['update_time']` is empty.. but can't understand why..

Comment: Try to check it in your dbms. Check the output of the select statement.

Comment: The SQL does not select `price`

Comment: $query = "select update_time from price";  your table name is **price** ? or is it field name ?

Comment: Yes, it's table name `price` and also column `price`

Comment: do one thing .. **"select *"** and check what you get .. **print_r** it

Comment: also noticed your values are empty here **$username = "";
     $password = "";
     $dbname = ""; **

Comment: You will NOT be able to echo `$row['price']` even if the `else` condition is reached because you have not selected `price` in the sql query so it is not part of the recordset

Comment: Okay I see what is happen here. As @BarneyStinson point to check times. I have connection to db I'm just removed credentials for the question. I have also selected with `*` so I get all fields.

Comment: great .. u see the differences of values over there now ..

Comment: Yes, and `54143` is always more than `3 * 3600`. So i need to do `<` not `>` right?

Comment: so now u r able to `echo $row['update_time']` ? y it was not working before ?

Comment: Yes, now `$row['update_time']` show `2016-10-26 16:06:46`

Comment: why it was not showing before then ? :) thats a mystery ..

Comment: I can't understand also why and what is happening here

Comment: you have checked the php error log presumably?

Comment: and yea one suggestion to you before asking questions ... instead of putting blank values for credentials like **$servername = "localhost";
     $username = "";
     $password = "";
     $dbname = ""; ** i would suggest you to put dummy names like "myDatabase"** and etc so it wont confuse the people while giving answers .. as they see them as blank values you know ..

Comment: @RamRaider no errors in log or on page. @Mittul point taken. I've edited the question and I've added dummy credentials. So correct condition here should be `if (time() - strtotime($row['update_time']) < 3 * 3600)` ?

Comment: so it fulfils your requirement now ? is it working now ?

Comment: You can check via sql query if `updated_date` is less or more than 3 hours. Dealing with times is a bit tricky because of different time zones etc. Just make your query with where clause and check time interval.

Comment: @S.I. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the query like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE update_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)";
```

Then based on this query

```
// your connection 

$query = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE update_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($res->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'not updated';
} else {
    echo 'updated';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static function getPrice() {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx"; 

    $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
    if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $query = "select `price`, `update_time` from `price`";
    $result = $conn->query( $query );

    $max = abs( 3 * 3600 );
    $price=false;

    if( $result ){
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            try{
                if ( abs( time() - strtotime( $row['update_time'] ) ) > $max ) {      

                    $urldata = get_curl_content( 'https://example.com/api' );
                    if( $urldata ){
                        $rates = json_decode( $urldata, TRUE );

                        $price = is_array( $rates ) && array_key_exists( 'USD', $rates ) ? $rates['USD'] : 'error';
                        echo 'a';
                    } else {
                        echo 'error fetching from api';
                    }
                } else {         
                    $price = $row['price']; 
                    echo 'b';       
                }
            }catch( Exception $e ){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Thank's but this again return info from api even I've updated db time before 5min. I.e. less than 3 hours and should be showing price from `else` block i.e. database

Comment: @Garg can you **var_dump** please  ? for both the variable values

Comment: the values you are comparing in if statement.

Comment: like `var_dump(abs( time() - strtotime( $row['update_time'] ) ))` and `var_dump($max)`

Comment: `var_dump($max) -> int(10800)`, `var_dump(abs( time() - strtotime( $row['update_time'] ) )) ->int(55411)`

Comment: how about changing **greatear (>)** to **lessthen(<)**  then ? do u need that to be changed based on your requirement ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave but then will become if `update_time` is updated less than 3 hours do if condition which will be incorrect unless I change places and put in IF condition `$price = $row['price'];` which will be the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126801/discussion-between-mittul-at-technobrave-and-garg).